# Detect Vector "out-of-range" error before action

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Is there a way to detect if my Vector is out-of-range before performing an action?

I tried

```
if (myVector[i] != null || myVector != undefined) {
 // do stuff here
}
```

But I am getting an out-of-range error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the index is <= the length of the vector, and change the order of your tests. I'm not a Flash guy, but in most C-like languages, it'll look like this:

```
if (myVector != undefined /* Make sure the vector isn't null*/ && i < myVector.length() /*Make sure it's in range*/ && myVector[i] != null){
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You detect if a Vector's index is out of range as follows:

```
                var myIndexValue:int;
                if(vector.length - 1 < myIndexValue) //you are out of range.
```